# Mock EntityManager in @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) for mvc testing

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have built an API that uses CriteriaQueries (since conditions are dynamic) for fetching data. There are many services involved in processing this data so I want to write end-to-end test cases.

Is there a way we can mock EntiyManager in test cases running with SpringRunner? I can see many answers related to MockitoJunit but none for SpringRunner. Is it not possible to do so? if so, then why?

Comment: Entirely possible. But I don't believe it is a good idea - mock your repositories instead.

Comment: do you mean I should keep the criteria queries in the repository service? and also, how is it possible exactly, i haven't been able to do so?